# how to deal with trailing white spaces using oracle sql select statement

Tags: sql, oracle, csv, removing-whitespace

I've imported a tab delimited into excel.  I've got a column with a data type of VARCHAR2(255) dumped from an Oracle database.

The data formatted in the column has data that look like this: (colon separated values)

```
info 1: info 2: info 3
```

After importing the file to excel worksheet, I have a few records where there is a problem in the formatting. Basically white spaces in between colons, causing the problems with the tabs.

The bad record would look like this. The record imports, but that data is misaligned within the spreadsheet.

```
info<...whitespace here...>1: info 2: info 3
```

Is there a way in Oracle syntax, sql that I can somehow select that column and remove the embedded white spaces so that it wouldn't break my tab import?

Comment: `I've imported a .csv file that is tab delimited.` sounds confusing. Is that a comma separated(csv) file or a tab delimited file? Also, the problem is while exporting data in to excel - is that right?

Answer (score 1):

This is just a pointer.
If I understood you correctly, you want to replace tabs(\t) with in selected column with spaces(\b) so that tab delimited import works in excel.

You may use replace funcation to remove tab. (or any other character as it may apply)

Example:

```
SELECT REPLACE(YOUR_COLUMN_NAME,CHR(9),' ') FROM ...
```

Assuming this meets your data requirements, this would replace tabs with spaces (or any character you mention instead of `' '`)

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
SELECT regexp_replace('info    :1 info 2: info 3','[[:space:]]{2,}', ' ') FROM dual;
```

Gives:

> info :1 info 2: info 3

Assuming you want to leave one space between 'info' and ':'

Answer (score 0):

problem: `Basically white spaces in between colons`

If the "data" (I use the term loosely, given the dreck you're working with) do not contain spaces, you could use the replace function to replace SPACE with "" (empty string) in a UDF.  Or you could replace all instances of SPACE:COLON and COLON:SPACE with COLON.